# if condition inside lambda while using posix path

Tags: python-3.x, lambda

So, I'm trying to remove hidden files from POSIX PATH i.e.

```
[PosixPath('/Users/abhimanyuaryan/../imagenette-160/.DS_Store'),
 PosixPath('/Users/abhimanyuaryan/../imagenette-160/train'),
 PosixPath('/Users/abhimanyuaryan/../imagenette-160/val')]
```

This `.DS_Store` doesn't make any sense here.

```
p = Path('/Users/abhimanyuaryan/../imagenette-160/')
```

I wrote this code. Tried adding if condition at back but I'm confused how do I do that. For a fact I know this code is wrong. Because even if it were a string. `.DS_Store` is not `x[0]`

It has to be after last `\`. I think I might need some regex here to find `\.` & then exclude it from POSIX PATH

but first I need to correct my if statement which doesn't seem to be correct

```
Path.ls = lambda x: list(x.iterdir()) if str(x)[0] != '.'
```

I also saw few labda and if usage questions on SO but didn't understand the correct syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to have an `else`:

```
Path.ls = lambda x: list(x.iterdir()) if str(x)[0] != '.' else None
```

I use `None` for example.

Comment: is the else part important syntactically?

Comment: @AbhimanyuAryan Yup otherwise what should the code assign to `Path.ls`